# Dynamically creating multiple dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I try to create new functionality which is dynamically created multiple dropdown menus. To this I'm using jQuery. I reached to problem I can't pass. Below is code which create "themeMenu" - this is first level dropdown list.

```
function addTheme(addBtn) {
$navTheme = $("#themeNavbar");

var $themeDropdown = $("<div>", { id:"themeDropdown", class: "dropdown" });

var $buttonDropdown = $("<button>", { class: "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle mr-1", type: "button" });
$buttonDropdown.attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
$buttonDropdown.attr("aria-haspopup", "true");
$buttonDropdown.attr("aria-expanded", "false")
$buttonDropdown.popover();
$buttonDropdown.mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(this).dropdown("toggle");
});

var $buttonNameInput = $("<input>", { class: "text-dark w-75 theme-Name", type: "text", value: "Nowy temat" });
$buttonNameInput.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.charCode === 13)
        applyName($buttonNameInput[0], e);
})

var $themedDMenu = $("<div>", { class: "dropdown-menu mt-0" });
$themedDMenu.attr("aria-labelledby", "themeDropdown");
$themedDMenu.mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(this).prev().dropdown("toggle");
})

var $addLinkButton = $("<a>", { class: "dropdown-item btn-manage", href: "#", text: "Dodaj" });
$addLinkButton.click(function (e) {
    addLink($addLinkButton, e);
})

var $divider = $("<div>", { class: "dropdown-divider" });
var $editLinkButton = $("<a>", { class: "dropdown-item btn-manage", href: "#", text: "Edytuj" });
var $deleteLinkButton = $("<a>", { class: "dropdown-item btn-manage", href: "#", text: "Usuń" });

$themedDMenu.append($addLinkButton);
$themedDMenu.append($divider);
$themedDMenu.append($editLinkButton);
$themedDMenu.append($deleteLinkButton);

$buttonDropdown.append($buttonNameInput);

$themeDropdown.append($buttonDropdown);
$themeDropdown.append($themedDMenu);

$navTheme.append($themeDropdown);
}
```

And here is code I using to create "themeLink" which is second level dropdown menu appended to first level. addLink() function is executed when $addLinkButton was clicked.

```
function addLink(addBtn, e) {

var newLink = $("<div>", { class: "dropdown-item"});

var newLinkHtml = $("<div>", { class: "dropright" });

var newLinkDropdown = $("<a>", {class: "dropdown-toggle"});
newLinkDropdown.attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");//.popover();
newLinkDropdown.attr("aria-haspopup", "true");
newLinkDropdown.attr("aria-expanded", "false");
newLinkDropdown.mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(this).dropdown("toggle");
})

var newLinkInput = $("<input>", { class: "text-dark w-75 theme-Name", type: "text", value: "Nowy link" });
newLinkInput.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.charCode === 13)
        applyName(newLinkInput[0], e);
})

var newLinkDropdownMenu = $("<div>", { class: "dropdown-menu" });
newLinkDropdownMenu.mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(this).prev().dropdown("toggle");
    //e.preventDefault();
});

var editBtn = $("<a>", { class: "dropdown-item btn-manage", href: "#", text: "Edytuj" });
editBtn.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    var dDToggle = $($this.parent(".dropdown-menu")[0].previousSibling);

    if (dDToggle.hasClass("named")) {
        var newLinkInput = $("<input>", { class: "text-dark w-75 theme-Name", type: "text", value: "Nowy link" });
        newLinkInput.keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.charCode === 13)
                applyName(newLinkInput[0], e);
        })
        dDToggle.html(newLinkInput);
    }
})

var deleteBtn = $("<a>", { class: "dropdown-item btn-manage", href: "#", text: "Usuń" });
deleteBtn.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    var linkToRemove = $this.parents(".dropdown-item");
    linkToRemove.remove();
})

newLinkDropdownMenu.append(editBtn);
newLinkDropdownMenu.append(deleteBtn);

newLinkDropdown.append(newLinkInput);

newLinkHtml.append(newLinkDropdown);
newLinkHtml.append(newLinkDropdownMenu);

newLink.append(newLinkHtml);

addBtn.before(newLink);
}
```

As you can see my dropdownlists react on mouse evenets - not only on *click()*. When mouse pointer enter on **$buttonDropdown** then everything works fine. *dropdown()* method toggle class "show" for **$themeDropdown**, **$themedDMenu**  and toggle "aria-expanded" attr on **$buttonDropdown**. Problem occur when pointer enter on **newLinkDropdown**. Method *dropdown()* works not only for second level dropdown list elements (**newLinkHtml**, **newLinkDropdown**,**newLinkDropdownMenu**)  but also on first level elements (**$themeDropdown**, **$themedDMenu**,**$buttonDropdown**). In effect my first level dropdown list enter into show-hide loop. When first level dD list is static (added in html file) then this problem doesn't occur. But I wrote jQuery code based on html code so I suppose it will be works.
Sorry, my code needs refactoring :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i did some research and find solution and answer. I used `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of `<div>` everywhere. Very good example I found     [here](https://codepen.io/svnt/pen/beEgre). Also I discovered that this solution works with Firefox but not with Chrome on which I tested my App. Finally I found this case     [Bootstrap 4 Navbar with Dropdown and sub-dropdown](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21026)